What is the best architecture for multi-target text regression?
I'm building an AI model using Google's 'Civil-Comments' dataset. It has 7 different labels, each a float than can be anywhere from 0 to 1. Embedding Bags, which I have read about. do not perform well. I've been looking into transformers and recurrent systems (LSTM, GRU, RNN, etc.). What should I do?
Using PyTorch, if it matters. But I'm not looking for code.

Just to clarify, the task here is to classify a comment into 7 floats between 0 and 1? What is the meaning of 0 and 1? Why do you have 7 labels?

@nbro I have seven labels, one for each type of language. The Civil-Comments dataset is where I'm getting my data from. 0 means that type of language (eg. threats) are detected, whereas 1 means it is there and it is severe. The closer to1, the more prevalent the language used.
